# Find discrepancy for $0,\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{4}{n^2}, \cdots,\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $w = (x_n), n= 1, 2, \dots $ be a given sequence of real numbers. For a positive integer $N$ and a subset $E$ of $I$, let the counting function $A(E; N; w)$
be defined as the number of terms $x_n$, $1 \leq n \leq N$, for which $\{x_n\}\in E$ (where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part). If
there is no risk of confusion, we shall often write $A(E; N)$ instead of
$A(E; N; w)$. Here is our basic definition.

The sequence $w = (x_n), n = 1, 2, \dots$ of real numbers is
said to be uniformly distributed modulo $1$ (abbreviated u.d. m)  if for
every pair $a, b$ of real numbers with $0 < a < b < 1$ we have
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{A([a.b);N;w)}{N} = b-a.$$

For a finite sequence $x_1, \dots, x_N$ of real numbers, we define $$D_N = D(x_1,\cdots,x_N) = \sup_{0 < \alpha \leq 1} \left|\frac{A([0,\alpha);N)}{N} - \alpha\right|.$$

For $n \geq 1$ let $w_n$ be the sequence $$0,\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{4}{n^2}, \cdots,\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}.$$

Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } D(w_n) = \frac{1}{4}$

I am stuck on this problem can you give me some ideas or hints for solving this?

Comment: @metamorphy No, don't have now idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n$. Then we see that all the values of $x_k$'s lie in $[0,1)$. So, the fractional part of any $x_k$ is $x_k$.

Split the set of values that $\alpha$ can take into union of sets $S_i=\left[\dfrac{(i-1)^2}{n^2}, \dfrac{i^2}{n^2}\right)$ for all $2\le i<n$, $S_1=\left(0, \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$ and $S_n=\left[\dfrac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}, 1\right]$

For $\alpha\in S_i, A([0,\alpha), n)=i$ since $0, \dfrac{1}{n^2},...,\dfrac{(i-1)^2}{n^2}$ will be only terms whose value lies in $[0,\alpha)$

So, $\sup_{\alpha\in S_i} \left|\dfrac{A([0,\alpha), n)}{n}-\alpha\right|=\sup_{\alpha\in S_i}\left|\dfrac{i}{n}-\alpha\right|=\sup_{\alpha\in S_i}\left(\dfrac{i}{n}-\alpha\right)=\dfrac{i}{n}-\dfrac{(i-1)^2}{n^2}=\dfrac{-i^2+(n+2)i-1}{n^2}$ 
We get that $\sup_{0<\alpha\le 1} \left|\dfrac{A([0,\alpha), n)}{n}-\alpha\right|=\sup_{1\le i\le n}\left(\dfrac{-i^2+(n+2)i-1}{n^2}\right)$
Now for even $n$, supremum value is the value when $i=\dfrac{n+2}{2}$ and for odd $n$, supremum value is the value when $i=\dfrac{n+1}{2}$ or $\dfrac{n+3}{2}$ since $i$ takes only integer values. (Here we have used minimization of a quadratic function)

Expand the expression in both cases and you can show that the required limit is $\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the definitions. The quantity $A([0,\alpha);n;w_n)$ is the number of nonnegative integers $k$ such that $k^2/n^2\in[0,\alpha)$, that is, $0\leqslant k<n\sqrt\alpha$. Thus $A([0,\alpha);n;w_n)=\lceil n\sqrt\alpha\rceil$ and $$D(w_n)=\sup_{0<\alpha\leqslant 1}\left|\frac{\lceil n\sqrt\alpha\rceil}{n}-\alpha\right|=\sup_{0<\alpha\leqslant 1}\left(\frac{\lceil n\sqrt\alpha\rceil}{n}-\alpha\right).$$ Finally, use $n\sqrt\alpha\leqslant\lceil n\sqrt\alpha\rceil<n\sqrt\alpha+1$ to conclude with $$\lim_{n\to\infty}D(w_n)=\sup_{0<\alpha\leqslant 1}(\sqrt\alpha-\alpha)=\frac14.$$